# ToolstripContainer save layout in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstripcontainer

Hi 
I am currently working with tabstrips contained in a toolstripcontainer [Winforms, C#]. What I would like to do is, save the layout of these tabstrips and load them again, when the form is loaded. I was pretty surprised to find, that it has not been developed intrinsically.

If anybody can help me this, that would be great.

Thanks for your time and patience.

With Regards
gagan janjua

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ToolstripManager seems to solve the problem. The only issue ( i.e. bug in VS2010, as i have found out ) is that the settings are only persisted when the toolstrips are contained in different ToolstripContainers. If they are in the same parent, the layout is not persisted.

Thanks